# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error happens when I try to load a different scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, terminate, sigabrt

How do I fix this problem I've looked at other answers but can't figure out my problem.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tap_Car.GameOver setNormalTexture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10123acf0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x184406fd8 0x182e68538 0x18440def4 0x18440af4c 0x184306d2c 0x193b60228 0x184e56420 0x184e5cf00 0x184df283c 0x184e56420 0x184e55b58 0x193b4f8ac 0x193b65738 0x193b15bb8 0x10009ec84 0x10009ed24 0x193b4f3c8 0x193b65738 0x193b15bb8 0x184e56420 0x184e55b58 0x193b4ed50 0x100099a0c 0x100099848 0x100094064 0x10009416c 0x18a403f14 0x18a401f84 0x193b18cf8 0x193b386dc 0x193b35188 0x193b3465c 0x193b3628c 0x193b6b7b4 0x100f344fc 0x187616600 0x1876164b0 0x184673dd4 0x18439d958 0x1843b5adc 0x1843b527c 0x1843b2d90 0x1842e2d94 0x185d4c074 0x18a59b130 0x10009f9ec 0x1832f159c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

this happens when this code runs

```
let gameover = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")!
    gameover.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    view?.presentScene(gameover, transition:    SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.4))
```

and this is the code for "GameOverScene"

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GameOver: SKScene{

    var restart = SKLabelNode()
    var highscorelbl = SKLabelNode()
    var homescreen = SKLabelNode()
    var scorelbl = SKLabelNode()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        restart = self.childNode(withName: "restart") as! SKLabelNode
        highscorelbl = self.childNode(withName: "highscore") as! SKLabelNode
        homescreen = self.childNode(withName: "homescreen") as! SKLabelNode
        scorelbl = self.childNode(withName: "score") as! SKLabelNode
        if highscoredefault.value(forKey: "highscore") != nil{
            highscore = highscoredefault.integer(forKey: "highscore")
            highscorelbl.text = "High Score: \(highscore)"}
        scorelbl.text = "Score: \(score)"


    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let touchlocation = touch.location(in: self)
            if atPoint(touchlocation).name == "restart"{
                let gamescene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
                gamescene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                view?.presentScene(gamescene, transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: (0.8)))
            }


            if atPoint(touchlocation).name == "homescreen"{
                let gamemenu = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameMenu")!
                    gamemenu.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                    view?.presentScene(gamemenu, transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: (0.8)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't present a scene on SKScene.  What you are trying to do would be like adding a subView on UIView.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: ***[Tap_Car.GameOver setNormalTexture:]: unrecognized selector sent...*** that means your class `GameOver` class lacks the method (aka setter) `setNormalTexture`.

Comment: This code doesn't produce the crash you are talking about. Put an exception breakpoint and see what line crashes. And avoid using that much forced downcastings and forced unwrappings in Swift. At least not for a production.

Comment: @Whirlwind I used the break points to find what lines cause the crash and the variables in the "gameover" class are the ones that are causing the crash. I can't figure out why tho I've got another very similar class with the same type of variables and they work fine